# Página que leia o feed com título, imagem e snippet

Tags: php, html, feed

Preciso criar uma página em php, com feed do site que exiba as últimas publicações com nome, imagem e uma snippet. Consegui fazer o código, mas ele exibe a publicação completa;
* Gostaria de saber, onde estou errando, e como poderia corrigir, com uma explicação o mais detalhada possível para melhor entendimento.

Comment: Exemplifique melhor, se possível com código, o que já tem e etc...

Comment: Coloque o código de sua página para que alguém possa te dar um sinal de luz mais forte, mas lembre-se de remover qualquer informação de seus servidores e outros...